# Change the background color of a button with Delphi XE5 and FireMonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I am creating a style for the button component firemonkey, I can even put the rectangle in background but when I run the application the background prevents me click the button. What am I doing wrong? It seems that the rectangle is in front of the button preventing the click. Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately there's not enough info here for us to be able to troubleshoot your issue. What do you mean by "put the rectangle in background"?

Comment: Unfortunately I can not post pictures yet, my profile does not liberate, it would be easier to explain. 

When I mention Rectangle mean the TRectangle component of the Shapes palette. That saw the need to use one of them to be able to change the color of the TButton component, using it as the background TButton (by changing the Style Designer FireMonkey). 

I hope I was able to explain better.

Comment: Give us links to off site image sharing sites and we'll edit them in to the Q

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that you need to activate HitTest on the TButton component properties.
With this you solve the problem of the Click event on the TButton component.

Comment: Perfect Juan, you've solved the problem, that was it. For those who are having the same problem I go in the StyleDesigner FireMonkey, the option button style, place a TRectangle within the background of this option, adjust colors as you want and let the TRectangle HitTest property to False, ready, your TButton now be customized and fully functional.

Comment: lost 3 hours thinking that my code was wrong, but the truth was that I couldn't click my button. Thanks a ton!